# How can I test my resume against an application tracking system (ATS)

Tags: pdf

I recently made my new resume in HTML/CSS instead of using a template/traditional document. The end result is still a pdf (by printing the page to pdf) but I've heard that tables (which I use for simple organisation) among other things might cause problems.

I was looking if I can find a free ATS to test my resume on to see what parts of it might fail to be collected properly.

Comment: The problem is that you would have to test it for ***all*** ATS to be completely sure.